# Book about man searching for mythological creatures.

Tags: story-identification, books

I can't remember the title whatsoever. Basically the book was following a boy/man? Who found this book I think and was searching for mythological creatures. I know he traveled by some kind of submarine, that also flew. The only other detail I can remember is by the end of the book, he's captured by harpies, and was either nearly killed or left a message to the reader to save him.

Comment: Usually it helps if you can give a rough estimate of the date of publication. If you can recall any other details, such as what the cover looked like, or any other minor details, please include those as well.